# What was the purpose of the two-way mirror in the Cabin?

Tags: the-cabin-in-the-woods

One of the joys of *Cabin in the Woods* is that everything that we know from "standard" horror movies gets an explanation.  The creepy warning, the reading of the Latin, the character archetypes, etc, everything is there for a reason.  But one thing I just realized that I didn't understand was the two-way mirror that the Sacrifices find early in the film.

What was the point of that?  It doesn't seem to play into them "choosing," like the Harbinger and the items in the basement do, and it doesn't have any apparent surveillance benefit for the technicians, given that they've got every room wired and it was covered up.  I can't recall any other discoveries that show the cabin to be "more than just a cabin" like this, so it seems like it wasn't actually meant to be found.  At the same time, the techinicians seem utterly unfazed by its discovery.

For a few minutes I thought it may be a hold-over from the days before the whole operation was computerized, but it seems odd for the technicians to risk entering the cabin *during* the ritual just to see into one of the other rooms.  Aside from the risk to them personally, it would risk the Sacrifices seeing them if they ran into the adjoining room before the technician could hide.

Am I forgetting anything from the movie that revealed the purpose of the two-way mirror, or does its presence go unexplained?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they wanted them to find it. They covered it with the ugliest picture they could find in the hopes that the athlete or the scholar would spy on the whore or the virgin and have a husband's bulge.

Comment: I agree that it seems like they wanted them to find it, but why?  I'm assuming you're kidding about the husband's bulge, but I honestly can't think of any reason for it *except* voyeurism, which benefits the technicians or the ritual not at all.

Comment: I'm guessing the discovery of one secret would encourage them to search the cabin for others, thus leading them to the cellar. Also, the generation of sexual tension is a key part of the ritual since the sacrifices need to prove that the whore is genuinely whorish.

Comment: That's as good an explanation as I've heard, but it doesn't seem to match the events of the plot: the Sacrifices don't go on to find the cellar because of that discovery, and the technicians make no mention of needing to pick up the slack or change plans in order to reveal it.  And as for the sexual tension with the Whore, it isn't the Whore's room.  I suppose it could be reinforcing the virginal modesty of the Virgin, and setting up her "chemistry" with the scholar, but it seems like an awkward way of doing that given the chemicals and other means at the technicians' disposal.

Comment: there's a line in the script about needing to change "the story" because of the room change (he wasn't supposed to be a gentleman) and they then comment on how they've been mucking with the whore's libido. Clearly the sexual tension angle is a big thing for them.

Comment: @Richard: "Husband's bulge?" Did you teleport here from 1950.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - It's a quote from the film

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Much like the other furnishings of the cabin, the two-way mirror and the horrendous painting covering it were designed to increase the atmosphere of the cabin and the tension of the group. The entire scenario revolved around placing the youngsters in a remote location where they would feel helpless, yet also prompting them to explore the environment (where they would eventually find the basement and choose a fate). Nothing prompts exploration like a mystery.

There was also a noted attempt to build sexual tension among the group, of which the mirror likely played a part. Specific comments made by

> the technicians monitoring the situation indicated that they wanted the male on the viewing side to watch the unknowing female.

The fact that this didn't happen was a minor annoyance to them, both plan-wise and personally (since they didn't get to watch her undress).

You are correct in stating that everything had a purpose, since as we find out

> everything that occurred - with the exception of The Fool and The Virgin finding their way into the facility (and the events that followed) - was carefully orchestrated to complete the ritual, even the old man at the very beginning before they even reach the cabin.

Comment: I feel like, in general, the "guy spying on a girl in a compromising situation" is a horror movie trope, generally used to either set the guy up for seeing the girl get killed (but cast doubt on his credibility due to the circumstances) or to have him be distracted enough to be killed himself. However, I can think of no good examples off of the top of my head.

Comment: Agreed - I've seen it in numerous horror movies as well, going back to the late 70's. I think - from a film-making perspective - it has to do with the relations between voyeurism and repressed sexuality (which is an aspect of most movie killers).

Comment: @SeanDuggan - As an added bonus, one of the first horror movies I ever saw had a scene with a guy watching a girl bathe through the keyhole. It was called "The Unseen" way back in 1980. So that trope's definitely been around for a while.

Comment: I think that, in addition to potentially prompting them to explore, it could also have served as a sign that there was something weird about the cabin, which *could* prompt them to leave. So in that sense, it could be a part of their "choice," like a lesser Harbinger.